# Display table with contentEditable collapsing

Tags: html, css

For a reason i need to use `display:table` on an `h1`.
But, when using `contenteditable` with `table`, the element will collapse(dissapear) **if one delete all text from it**. You must leave one character otherwise it disappears and you can't type text again.

```css
.element {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="element" contenteditable="true">Content</h1>
```

Is there away to use a `table` display but avoid element collapsing when all text has been removed? (both desktop and mobile)

I have tried to set a `min-width` which didn't help.

Comment: add extra padding or a pseudo to simulate a placeholder while the element is empty.

Comment: tried padding - not working (also for display block), and to simulate a placeholder its not possible because then the user needs to delete it all again...

Comment: set a width to your element, 1em or so, it will expand if content becomes longer, that's the native table-layout propertie . it shrinks or expands to hold content.

Comment: thanks, this is not working, you can try. it will simply dissapear.

Comment: Okay, which browser are you using to test this ? it is supposed to work for every browsers , including IEs since IE8 ;)

Comment: works only on Firefox, fail on Chrome/Safari on my mac

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what you are trying to achieve is not supposed to be done with a HTML table element, so you wont be able to get it down with `display: table`. 
If you rather put

```
.element {
  display: table-cell;
  min-widht: 1px;
}
```

you could theoretically achieve what you want, but again if it fits your needs.

Comment: thanks ! this works but i need table, or block. min-width will not work with a block, it will also collapse.

Answer (score 1):

a width for a table *(or element set to `display:table;`)* is alike a `min-width` :

set a `width` to the element, it will expand if needed .

```css
.element {
  display: table;
  width:1em;/* whatever seems fine to you */
  border:solid;/* see me , demo */
}
.element:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="element" contenteditable="true">Content</h1>
<h1 class="element" contenteditable="true"></h1>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout
>
> The `table-layout` CSS property sets the algorithm used to lay out `<table>` cells, rows, and columns.

default value is `auto` for any element using the `display` table layout  .

---

for a tricky one i would not use, use grid :

```css
.element {
  display:grid;
  width:max-content;
  max-width:100%;
  grid-template-columns:minmax(1.2em,auto);
  grid-template-rows   :minmax(1.2em,auto);
  border:solid;
  padding-right:0.1em;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="element" contenteditable="true">Content</h1>
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is working here, but does not work on my mac, no matter what i tried.

Comment: tried on Chrome for mac, its not working. what happens is that the width stay but the height collapse. trying to also set height will not work. I am using a google font. ( if i set a border, it turns to be a line which mean width stay, height collapse)

Comment: tried also on a well know Chrome simulator, its not working : <h1  contenteditable=true style="display:table; width:1em; background-color:red;">dfdfdf</h1>

Comment: @paulseems You might need to add an empty pseudo, so it stands on the baseline and produce at least one line  : `.element:after {content:'';display:inline-block;}` I have no MAC to test on , but it should be enugh to let the element to be at least the height of line-height's value at the minimum.

Comment: Ok , i would like to confirm that this answer is wrong. Take the link to this question, run the snippet on Chrom or Safari, right from your answer, and it fails.

Comment: your codepen fail on my mac, in Chrome and as well as in Safari.

Comment: okay, for my chrome it works in codepen : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/oNjVZym or here with the snippet updated, i guess without a Mac i won't be able to help further. :(  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug7gc.jpg

Comment: thank you very much, you don't have to go further, i just run it on a mac and it won't work, i don't have to be so smart :) how is it possible that the same thing work on chrome in one machine and not the other ? otherwise all browsers compatibility charts are useless ???